# Saxon HE 9 With Beckers Merge.xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, saxon

I'm trying to merge some xml files together using saxon9He.jar and Oliver Becker's merge.xslt.

For the most part the merges are successful however for some elements the actual data is merging together for example:

I'm expecting two files of the format

```
<book>
     <publishedDate>
         2013-11-06
     </publishedDate>
 </book>
 <book>
    .....
```

What i am getting however is multiple published dates merging together in the same element
e.g.

```
<book>
     <publishedDate>
         2013-11-0622-04-1223-05-05
      </publishedDate>
 </book>
      .....
```

On some occasions there are maybe twenty or thirty different elements merging together. Whilst others are coming out as i require which is very odd...

currently i am calling it through a script as follows

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar f1.xml merge.xslt with=f2.xml > result.xml
```

The xslt is the :http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/merge/merge.xslt.html

Can anyone tell me if there are any flags which would force child elements to merge separately?
Alternatively could anyone point me in the right direction for modifying the xslt to achieve the output i require?

Comment: This XSLT code is compatible with Saxon 5.4.1 - might be this is causing the problem. If you provide complete XML input examples (somewhat reduced in length and complexity but still containing the problem you are facing), we can check against other versions of Saxon.

Comment: Thank's for the reply i will try it on other versions and see the result's thanks for the tip!

Comment: If the problem persists, you'd need to post accurate input XML in order to get help.

Comment: I would need to see your input documents, but the documentation at http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/#merge suggests to me that your expectations of what the stylesheet does are probably wrong.

Comment: @MathiasMüller You where absolutley spot on i tried saxon 5.4.1 seemed to fix the problem, thankyou for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. In this case, I will post an answer to help clean up SO - i.e. to prevent this question from remaining in the "unanswered" tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Taken from the comments section to close the question.)

This XSLT code (http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/merge/merge.xslt.html) is compatible with Saxon 5.4.1. As they behaviour of XSLT processors is not 'set in stone' and can change with new versions, this might cause your problem.

If you provide complete XML input examples (somewhat reduced in length and complexity but still containing the problem you are facing), we can check against other versions of Saxon.

On a different note, as suggested by @Michael Kay, it is as yet unclear whether the purpose of this stylesheet meets exactly your requirements.